# Javascript File Drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to get the absolute file path of a drop event using Javascript, or should I use another technology? If so, I can do the same with folders?

Comment: Have you found a solution or a alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript in a web browser is not going to give you absolute file paths from client machines.

Also see this about HTML5 drag-and-drop: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Comment: +1 for the article, I don't think I've seen profanity in any other PPK blog post, so I was a bit surprised but I LOLed.