# javascript ondrop event

Tags: javascript

I'm using the drop event in JavaScript to upload files using the following code:

```
var fileName = event.dataTransfer.files[0].name;            
var orgValue = document.getElementById('<%=tbfilesCollections.ClientID%>').value;
if (orgValue == 'undefined') {
    orgValue = '';
}
orgValue += orgValue == '' ? '' : '\n';
orgValue += "*" + fileName;
document.getElementById('<%=tbfilesCollections.ClientID%>').value = orgValue;
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

But this code only gets the file name... I need to get the full path of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this post points out, you cannot get the full path as you would like: [Javascript File Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025841/javascript-file-drop).

As mentioned in the comments by Michael Sandino, there is a way to do this in Firefox with the "mozFullPath" attribute, but I have yet to see a universally-implemented way of accomplishing this.

The reason for this I would imagine is that the browser shouldn't divulge information regarding the folder structure of a client computer to a web application, which is understandable.

Comment: thanks ... but how can get the full path of the file like google drive for ex.

Comment: Firefox has a mozFullPath attribute on the File object ... but that's not portable obviously

Comment: Again I don't believe this is possible in a durable, browser-independent way, and is certainly unnecessary. The point is that the file is uploaded, the server does not need and should not need the full path. Even if you go so far as to use an `<input type="file" />` and get the `value` after a file selection, you will only get the name and not the path, even though the full path is written into the field.